# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un objeto en la sesión? y ¿Cómo utilizarlo en un JSP? Servlet Web

Tags: java, jsp, session

Tengo este Servlet en el cual voy a recibir el nombre y la contraseña del objeto `request` para posteriormente validar si existe en la base de datos y consultar su nombre completo. Pero una vez creado el objeto de tipo `UsuarioDTO` no sé cómo guardarlo en la sesión para mostrar la propiedad `nombreCompleto` en varios *JSP*:

```
@WebServlet("/One")
public class One extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* Se crea el usuario */
        UsuarioDTO usuario = new UsuarioDTO();
        usuario.setIdUsuario(1);
        usuario.setNombre("jperez");
        usuario.setNombreCompleto("Juan Pérez López");

        //Aquí necesito meter el usuario a la sesión antes de que se
        //vaya a la página principal

        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/principal.jsp");
    }
}
```

Este es el [*DTO*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_Transferencia_de_Datos_(DTO)):

```
public class UsuarioDTO {

    private long idUsuario;
    private String nombre;
    private String nombreCompleto;

    public long getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }
    public void setIdUsuario(long idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getNombreCompleto() {
        return nombreCompleto;
    }   
    public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto) {
        this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

➊ Primeramente recuperas el objeto `HttpSession`:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Sobre interfaz `HttpSession`, Arun Gupta<sup>1</sup> dice:

> La interfaz `HttpSession`  se puede utilizar para ver y manipular  información de una sesión tales como el identificador de sesión y la hora de creación, y para vincular objetos a la sesión. [...] Los métodos `session.setAttribute` y `session.getAttribute` son usados para enlazar/ligar los objetos a la sesión.

➋ Luego asigna tu objeto con un nombre como un atributo en la sesión. Es decir, por ejemplo:

```
session.setAttribute("usr", usuario);
```

En tu código:

```
/* Se crea el usuario */
UsuarioDTO usuario = new UsuarioDTO();
usuario.setIdUsuario(1);
usuario.setNombre("jperez");
usuario.setNombreCompleto("Juan Pérez López");

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("usr", usuario);

response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/principal.jsp");
```

➌ Y en tu JSP (`principal.jsp`) puedes utilizar [*Expression Language* (EL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm) para mostrar los datos. Esto es, por ejemplo:

```
<p>Id Usuario: <strong>${usr.idUsuario}</strong></p>
<p>Nombre: <strong>${usr.nombre}</strong></p>
<p>NombreCompleto: <strong>${usr.nombreCompleto}</strong></p>
```

✱ *Addendum*

Debido a que utilizas el método `response.sendRedirect`, el navegador tiene que hacer otra petición al servidor para mostrar el JSP correspondiente (la URL en el navegador cambia),  por lo que necesitas tener el objeto en la sesión, es decir, en el objeto `session`.

No obstante, si utilizaras el método `request.getRequestDispatcher`, sólo necesitarías tener el objeto en la petición actual, es decir, en el objeto `request`. Y el navegador no necesitaría hacer otra petición (en este caso, la URL del navegador sigue siendo la misma).

---

*Notas*

1. Gupta, Arun. *Java EE 7 essentials.* Sebastopol, CA: O'Reilly Media, 2013.

Comment: existe alguna restricción entre aplicativos que se encuentren en el mismo server? ejemplo, tengo 3 aplicaciones en 1 servidor, una que controla el menu y 2 aplicaciones que interactuan con datos de usuario. (independientes). al agregar un dato en la session que debe ir de un aplicativo a otro pierdo el dato, y no puedo recuperarlo en el otro aplicativo... habrá que hacer algún paso extra?

Answer (score 0):

Se debe de crear una variable de sesión de la siguiente manera:

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
session.setAttribute("name",name);
```

Puedes setear los atributos que necesites y para obtenerlos utilizas el get del atributo:

```
session.setAttribute("name");
```

En tu JSP quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<% out.print(session.getAttribute("name")); %>
```

Para mayor referencia puedes ocupar el siguiente tutorial:

[Servlet session](http://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-http-session-login-and-logout-example)

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un objeto de tipo sesión dentro de tu clase java:

```
HttpSession miSesion = request.getSession(true);
```

Luego debes agregar el atributo que quieras almacenar, asignándole un identificador y el valor, en tu caso:

```
miSesion.setAttribute("nombreCompleto",usuario.getNombreCompleto());
```

De esta forma ya has almacenado un valor en una sesión.

Para poder recuperar el valor almacenado debes emplear el método Get, ejemplo:

```
String nombreUsuario = miSesion.getAttribute("nombreCompleto");
```

De esta forma ya puedes traspasarlo o recuperarlo directamente desde tu JSP.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tengo que desaconsejar las respuestas que hay que se basan en scriptlets (el `<% %>` y el `<%= %>`), que están considerados deprecados. Si estás trabajando en un proyecto con scriptlets mantenlo así, pero nuevos proyectos deberían usar Expression Language (EL) o al menos JSTL.

Para meter un objeto en un `session`, coincido con las otras preguntas, aunque recomiendo meter el DTO completo.

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
session.setAttributemiSesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
```

Para usar el bean mediante EL, simplemente haz

```
${usuario.nombreCompleto}
```

en el JSP. Esto buscará el bean `usuario` en los distintos scopes (página, request, session y application) y, cuando lo encuentre, llamará al método `getNombreCompleto()`.

Tambien se puede usar dentro de tags JSTL:

```
 <c:if test="${usuario.nombreCompleto eq 'Pepe'}"/>
    Es pepito!
 </c:if>
 <c:if test="${usuario.nombreCompleto ne 'Pepe'}"/>
    No es pepito, es ${usuario.nombrecompleto}
 </c:if>
```

Si tu plataforma aún no soporta EL, puedes usar los tags JSP `useBean` y `getAttribute`

```
<jsp:useBean name="usuario">
<jsp:getProperty name="usuario" property="nombreCompleto">
```

Por cierto, si los datos del bean están relacionados con la petición y no con la sesión, lo más normal es guardar el bean como un atributo del `request` (`request.setAttribute()`) y hacer un *forward* en vez de un *redirect*<sup>1</sup>; eso hace que no se compartan esos datos con otras peticiones simultáneas. En este caso, el JSP no es alterado.

---

<sup>1</sup> Redirect indica al cliente (browser) que tiene que redirigirse a la nueva página, creando una nueva petición. Forward continúa el proceso de la misma petición en la URL que se le pasa, el navegador no hace nada.